# How to input password for sudo in the same command line (without expect)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

My goal: to run `sudo apt -y install expect` and not having to input any more input

Currently it asks for my password

```
dario@GPU15:~$ sudo apt -y install expect                                                                                                                                                                          
[sudo] password for dario:
```

I know how to workaround it with the `expect` command (`expect -c "spawn sudo command ; expect { dario: } { send password\n }; interact";`)

The `yes password | sudo apt -y install expect` command does not work for this.

How do I workaround it without the `expect` command, only with natively installed applications?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). (you may also try [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/))

Comment: In hindsight, I agree. Is there not a feature to move such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-S` option to read password from standard input

```
$ echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Answer (score -1):

Then go in:

**sudo su** //super user mode

type the password once, then just continue executing commands without typing psw anymore.